# Таймер с идентификатором

Tags: python, python-3.x

В общем, нужен таймер с идентификатором, который можно запускать, например, с "test", а потом и останавливать с этим же идентификатором. Он будет запускаться из функции, которая запускается и далее нужно будет остановить таймер вне функции.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но непонятный.

Comment: @Эникейщик быть может речь о декораторах? Вопрос действительно неясен.

Comment: Если я правильно понял задачу, то очень легко пишется с использованием `time.time()` и запоминанием идентификаторов в каком-нибудь словаре

Comment: @andreymal таймер будет иметь идентификатор с числовой переменной

Comment: А что именно у вас вызывает проблемы?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, как это должно работать, что именно вам нужно получить.